# MSMQ custom message format

Tags: c#, msmq

I would like to make message in MSMQ which will have text for example

```
<order><data id="5" color="blue"/></order>
```

This is standard XML. So far I have made Serializable class

```
[Serializable]
public class order
string id
string color
```

I am using BinaryFormatter. When i check the message.BodyStream there are some chars which are not supposed to be there( 00,01,FF ), then I cannot receive this message without error.

This task seems to be simple, just put text

```
<order><data id="5" color="blue"/></order>
```

into msmq.

Mine whole important code:

```
public static void Send()
    {
        using (message = new Message())
        {
            request req = new request("1", "blue");

                message.Recoverable = true;
                message.Body = req.ToString();
                message.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
                using (msmq = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\testrfid"))
                {
                    msmq.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
                    msmq.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.None);
                }
        }
    }

[Serializable]
public class request
{
    private readonly string _order;
    private readonly string _color;

    public request(string order, string color)
    {
        _order = order;
        _color = color;
    }
    public request()
    { }
    public string Order
    {
        get { return _order; }
    }
    public string Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(@"<request> <job order = ""{0}"" color = ""{1}"" /> </request>",_order,_color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: It's not polite to down-vote without leaving a comment.

Comment: In fact i have edited the question. The original form was very vague, so probably thats why.

Comment: You are not supposed to care what it looks like when using the `BinaryMessageFormatter`.  While you may be trying to serialize it into XML, the `BinaryMessageFormatter` makes no such assurances.  All that matters is that you are using the same formatter to read the message as you did to write the message.  It is not meant to be human-readable when using that formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found reason why the Message.Body contains these ascii characters before the string I pass to Body. I just fill directly BodyStream instead of Body and let it convert itself:

```
Message.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string i want to put as Body))
```

Then the message is simply only the string with nothing else.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to enforce the message format, but it does not seem to be possible, not in any distributed sense anyway. Now, about the extra bytes you see, they are probably a BOM (Byte Order Mark), which is a product of the encoding. UTF-8 should prepend `EF BB BF` (`ï»¿`), for example, so if you decode an UTF-8 byte array to ASCII, you will get `ï»¿` in the beginning of the result. I can not find anything on `00 01 FF` though, but I do believe that they represent a BOM. Read more on [BOM here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear at all; you can send any type of message you like to MSMQ, so long as you use the BinaryMessageFormatter.  Here's an example:

```
string error = "Some error message I want to log";

using (MessageQueue MQ = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\Your.Queue.Name"))
{
    BinaryMessageFormatter formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
    System.Messaging.Message mqMessage = new System.Messaging.Message(error, formatter);
    MQ.Send(mqMessage, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
    MQ.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the serializable class to send a string to a message queue.

Since you are using the BinaryMessageFormatter, you must first convert your string to a byte array using a text encoder e.g.

```
message.Body = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(req.ToString());
```

I'm just using UTF8 as an example, you can use whatever encoding you like.

Then when you read the message from the queue, remember to use the same encoding to get your string back e.g.

```
string myString = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(message.Body);
```

Hope this helps